# Auto add files to IPFS network

Tags: javascript, python, ipfs

On my Raspberry Pi, I have a Python script running that makes sure the room temperature is being measured (via a DHT22) and then log the temperature to a CVS file every half hour.

A new CVS file is created for everyday that the script is running. Therefore, the name of the files are `temp_dd-mm-yy.cvs`. These files are all saved in my `loggings` folder.

I now want to automatically pin add the cvs files to the IPFS network, because I don't want to write `ipfs add <file.cvs>` in the terminal every day.

In other words, is there a way to have a piece of code running that makes sure all files in the `logging` folder are added to IPFS network every 24 hours?

I have experimented with IPFS API, but I didn't manage to get anything useful out of that.

Answer (score 0):

From python directly, there is two ways to do this. Either you call the ipfs binary using the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) call command, or you directly use the REST api using something like [urllib](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/urllib.request.html).

For using the REST API, you have to add the data as a POST request, with the data being passed as form data.

Here is the equivalent curl request to add two "files":

```
$ curl -X POST -F 'file1=somedata' -F 'file2=somemoredata' http://localhost:5001/api/v0/add
{"Name":"QmaJLd3cTDQFULC4j61nye2EryYTbFAUPKVAzrkkq9wQ98",
  "Hash":"QmaJLd3cTDQFULC4j61nye2EryYTbFAUPKVAzrkkq9wQ98","Size":"16"}
{"Name":"Qman7GbdDxgT3SzkzeMinvUkaiVduzKHJGE5P2WGPqV2uq",
  "Hash":"Qman7GbdDxgT3SzkzeMinvUkaiVduzKHJGE5P2WGPqV2uq","Size":"20"}
```

With shell, you could just do a cron job that does e.g.

```
ipfs add -R /logging
```

every day. This will be reasonably efficient until your logging directory becomes *really* large even though it adds files again and again.

Of course, you will need to put the hashes somewhere or use IPNS so people can actually see this data.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution could be to use [ipfs-sync](https://github.com/TheDiscordian/ipfs-sync/) to keep the directory in-sync on IPFS. It'd keep a directory pinned for you, as well as update an IPNS key for you if you'd like a consistent address for the data.

It can also be tuned to only update IPNS every 24 hours if you desire.

Comment: Probably a good idea to disclose when recommending a library you maintain

Comment: I decided to remove the disclaimer. It just doesn't make sense to me. I work for PL, and it's the only software out there that does what I've described. It's just clutter.